# mod_rewrite for directory to another host

Tags: mod-rewrite, symfony, apache2

I need to rewrite and redirect all access to a directory to another host.
I'm using Symfony2 framework and the .htaccess is in the /web directory (also the root of the virtualhost) and looks like:

> RewriteEngine On 
>   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
>   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app.php [QSA,L]

I want all access to http://www.project1.com/foo redirected to http://www.project2.com/bar

How can I do that with htaccess?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put following line in .htaccess of root

```
RewriteRule ^foo/(.*) http://www.project2.com/bar/$1 [QSA,L,R=302]
```

Comment: OK, this works great :) And now to get the A ¿do you know how to avoid that the URL shown to the user changes to the new one?

Comment: You can't do that when you are pointing to different domain. It got security implications. If thats allowed you can redirect to facebook or google etc without changing display url, thats dangerous.