# Redirect to different URL Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

my www.gullak.co.vhost file contain 
when user request for www.gullak.co/remaining_path browser redirect to www.gullakmaster.com/remaining_path

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName gullak.co
ServerAlias www.gullak.co
DocumentRoot /home/ubuntu/Gullak-2/public
<Directory /home/ubuntu/Gullak-2/public/>
    AllowOverride All
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?gullak\.co$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.gullakmaster.com/ [L,R=301]
</Directory>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [mod\_rewrite for directory to another host](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5231109/mod-rewrite-for-directory-to-another-host)